# In PlasticSCM, how can I reparent a branch?

Tags: branching-and-merging, plasticscm

I created a branch and committed a changeset as a child of a child of my main branch.  I actually meant to shelve the changes and create a new branch off of my main branch.  How can I revert and/or make the branch a direct child of my main branch?

I have a hunch that I will need to [revert](http://www.plasticscm.com/releases/3.0/manuals_html/en/UserGuide-EN.htm#_Toc266201379) or do a [subtractive merge](http://www.plasticscm.com/releases/3.0/manuals_html/en/UserGuide-EN.htm#_Toc266201396).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PlasticSCM, the idea would similar to what is described below for Git:

- having a branch referring to your current commit
- reset the branch to the last correct commit
- use the [`switchbranchbase` command mention for PlasticSCM4](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2012/01/plastic-scm-30-to-40-migration-notes.html) or the simple merge mention in [this thread](http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/671-plastic-scm-4-rebase/).

  > - In PlasticSCM 3.0 to perform a rebase the steps were: Change branch base, update, merge.
  > - In PlasticSCM 4.0 is easier, just perform the merge from the branch you want to rebase.

---

Original answer in git:

If you have:

```
 x--x--x--x                 main
           \
            y--y--y         child
                   \
                    z--z    mybranch
```

You can do a:

```
git rebase --onto main child mybranch
```

That would give you:

```
            z'--z'          mybranch
           /
 x--x--x--x                 main
           \
            y--y--y         child
```

If you didn't want to rebase *all* of my branch, then a simple:

```
git checkout mybranch
git branch -b mynewbranch
git reset --hard z          # reset mybranch HEAD to the last commit before your new commit
git rebase --onto main mybranch mynewbranch
```

For a single commit, you could also use [`git cherry-pick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309), but I always prefer `git rebase`.

Comment: Gosh, this is a great answer and I apologize for not making it clearer that I needed an answer specific to PlasticSCM.  Just updated the title to reflect that.  Regardless, I still appreciate the excellent explanation (I do use Git a bunch).

Comment: @MicahDelaneBolen as in http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/671-plastic-scm-4-rebase/ ?

Comment: ...yes.  I guess I should accept your answer since `rebase` is the key ingredient in either scenario.  Again, my apologies.

Comment: @MicahDelaneBolen I have added command/links specifc for PlasticSCM.

Comment: That's the reason I love Plastic SCM so much! Great answer!!

Comment: @tuket That might have changed since my 2013 answer indeed.